# Is it possible to check if user has sound enabled by JS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I thought that there might be some Chrome functions that I can call by JS to decide what kind of notification should be used - video or written one...

Comment: Dont believe so, sound control is a system property which JS has 0 access to. (With good reason!)

Comment: well, that's what I though, but browser knows a lot about other system properties - such as resolution, operating system, etc. Why shouldn't browser know about sound? I don't see any good reason for that except techical - too many operating systems, too many different cards. Even skype doesn't know if user is hearing the sound...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.  The browser has no real knowledge that audio is enabled.  Even if it did, the sound can be turned down, muted, etc.